# Parsing an HTML document from the server

Tags: android, android-parser

I have an HTML on my server. When I try to parse this document with a DOM or PullParser, the parsing is very slow because I am parsing the HTML style too, mot only the data.

Do you know if there is something to do on Android and parse only the data and not the HTML style.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to **XMLPullParser** [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Comment: Thank you @Sadeshkumar Periyasamy, and for show the html content, I have to use a WebView?